# Eslint parsing error: `Unexpected token <` caused by underscore template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, eslint, prettier

Eslint throws `Parsing error: Unexpected token <`

There are a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow, but they don't cover my issue.

There is `template.js` file using the [underscore template](https://underscorejs.org/#template) method, which seems to be causing this error. I have tried adding `/* eslint-disable */` and `// eslint-disable-line` comments to ignore it, but the error was still occurring.

`template.js`:

```
'use strict';

const visit = require('unist-util-visit');
const nodeToString = require('hast-util-to-string');
<%= refractor %>

module.exports = options => {
// ...
}
```

`.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "plugins": ["node"],
  "rules": {
    "node/no-unsupported-features": ["error", {"version": 8}],
    "node/no-missing-require": ["error"]
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "underscore": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.0.0",
    "husky": "^0.13.4",
    "jest": "^24.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.4.4"
  },
```

I'm expecting Eslint to recognize underscore's templates, e.g. `<%= languages %>` and lint them properly.

Answer (score -1):

I created the ESLint plugin [`eslint-plugin-lodash-template`](https://github.com/ota-meshi/eslint-plugin-lodash-template).

If you install [`eslint-plugin-lodash-template`](https://github.com/ota-meshi/eslint-plugin-lodash-template) and configure [JavaScript templates](https://ota-meshi.github.io/eslint-plugin-lodash-template/#for-javascript-templates), it may solve your problem.